# Numeric Integration of discrete data

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab, singularity

I have discrete data points of the function plotted below:
[image]
I can have infinite number of points for this function.

First, I used the Trapezoidal rule (of Matlab).

Second, I used the interpolation function of Matlab to be able to use the built-in Integral function of Matlab (in which some adaptive approach is used in order to have a better approximation) as follows:

```
f1 = griddedInterpolant(x,y); %I used also spline and other methods
f2 = @(t) f1(t);
Result = Integral(f2,0,pi)
```

Comparing to my reference solution, both of those methods provide significant error(30% relative error). (I verified my code and the way i achieved the reference solution with another smooth function). The difference between using 1000 points or 1million points is negligible. I guess this shows that the problem is not related to round off error. However, I wanted to also use VPAINTEGRAL, but i cannot do it because i cannot convert the interpolated function to a symbolic form. Appreciate any suggestion how to use VPAINTEGRAL (or any other approaches...)

Comment: I think this is an interesting question that you haven't told us nearly enough to answer. Please [edit] the question to show us some more data. One possible problem: the function seems to be near $0$ for most of the domain.

Comment: How significant is significant error anyway? You may be expecting too much out of floating point arithmetic...

Comment: This function was numerically integrated by someone in a paper with significantly lower error. I am sure that something is wrong.

Comment: It looks smooth and periodic, so the trapezoidal rule should actually perform rather well. (Also, the fact that more points eventually doesn't help makes it *more* likely to be related to roundoff, not less. You could try using higher precision arithmetic to see if it helps.)